# Update nested parent classes in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to add a class to a parent container each time an "advanced" link is clicked.

So with jQuery I would just write something like..

```
$(this).closest('.row').addClass('overlay');
```

or

```
$(this).closest('section').addClass('overlay');
```

But it seems to be getting a little complex with Vue to just add a class to the parent container of the item that is clicked. I'm sure there is a more simple way to go about it.

Here is an example of my code.

```
<div id="app">
    <section v-bind:class="{ overlay: i == sectionActive && rowActive == null }" v-for="(section, i) in sections">
        <a href="#0" @click.prevent="toggleAdvanced(i)">Advanced</a>

        <div class="advanced-fields" v-bind:class="{ overlay: i == sectionActive && rowActive == null }">
            <fieldset>
                <label>
                    ID
                    <input type="text" name="section[id]" v-model="section.id">
                </label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>
                    Class
                    <input type="text" name="section[css_class]" v-model="section.css_class">
                </label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>

        <div class="row" v-bind:class="{ overlay: i == sectionActive && row_i == rowActive }" v-for="(row, row_i) in section.rows">
            <a href="#0" @click.prevent="toggleRowAdvanced(section, row)">Advanced</a>

            <div class="advanced-fields" v-bind:class="{ overlay: i == sectionActive && row_i == rowActive }">
                <fieldset>
                    <label>ID</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" v-model="row.id">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>CSS Class</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" v-model="row.css_class">
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        "sections": [{
            "id": "section-1",
            "css_class": "",
            "rows": [{
                "id": "",
                "css_class": ""
            }, {
                "id": "",
                "css_class": ""
            }]
        }, {
            "id": "section-2",
            "css_class": '',
            "rows": [{
                "id": "",
                "css_class": ""
            }]
        }],
        sectionActive: null,
        rowActive: null,
        columnActive: null
    },
    methods: {
        toggleAdvanced: function(index) {
            this.sectionActive = this.sectionActive === index ? null : index;
            this.rowActive = null;
            this.columnActive = null;
        },
        toggleRowAdvanced: function(section, row) {
            var sectionIndex = this.sections.indexOf(section);
            var rowIndex = section.rows.indexOf(row);

            this.sectionActive = this.sectionActive === sectionIndex ? null : sectionIndex;
            this.rowActive = this.rowActive === rowIndex ? null : rowIndex;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I need to do the same thing for columns but as you can see, it is getting too overly complicated. Any ideas on how to simplify this?

I know it would be easier to add a data attribute to each row, but I am saving the hash to a database and don't want to add in unnecessary data just for a UI toggle.

https://jsfiddle.net/ferne97/4jbutbkz/

Comment: For example, you can bind to a computed poperty or executed method where you hold your logic and which return class objects. This way you avoid repetitive code in a template. Also, you can look into `ref` attribute: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref if you want more jQuery-like approach, though it's not really recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a different approach and built several re-usable components. This removes all the complicated logic that you are putting into your Vue.

```
Vue.component("expand-link",{
    template:`<a href="#0" @click="toggle">Advanced</a>`,
  data(){
        return {
        expanded: false
    }
  },
  methods:{
    toggle(){
        this.expanded = !this.expanded
        this.$emit('toggled', this.expanded)
    }
  }
})

Vue.component("expanded-fields",{
    props:["details", "expanded"],
  template:`
        <div class="advanced-fields" :class="{overlay: expanded}">
            <fieldset>
                <label>
                    ID
                    <input type="text" name="section[id]" v-model="details.id">
                </label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>
                    Class
                    <input type="text" name="section[css_class]" v-model="details.css_class">
                </label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
  `
})

Vue.component("expandable-section", {
    props:["section"],
    template:`
    <section>
        <expand-link @toggled="onToggle"></expand-link>
      <expanded-fields :details="section" :expanded="expanded"></expanded-fields>
      <expandable-row v-for="row in section.rows" :key="row" :row="row"></expandable-row>
    </section>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
        expanded: false
    }
  },
  methods:{
    onToggle(val){
        this.expanded = val
    }
  }
})

Vue.component("expandable-row",{
    props:["row"],
    template:`
    <div class="row">
      <h3>Row</h3>
      <expand-link @toggled="onToggle"></expand-link>
      <expanded-fields :details="row" :expanded="expanded"></expanded-fields>
    </div>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
        expanded: false
    }
  },
  methods:{
    onToggle(val){
        this.expanded = val
    }
  }
})
```

And the template simply becomes

```
<div id="app">
  <expandable-section v-for="section in sections" :key="section" :section="section"></expandable-section>
  <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
</div>
```

Here is your fiddle [updated](https://jsfiddle.net/4jbutbkz/9/).

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to see a different approach.